# Group by separately and together?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
| counter_id | date        | sessions | campaign     | source        |
| -----------| ----------- | -------- | ------------ | ------        |
| 337        | 2022-05-01  |   25     | 12_WAVE_SALE | facebook      |
| 337        | 2022-05-01  |   100    | 12_WAVE_SALE | Not specified |
| 337        | 2022-05-01  |   75     | 12_WAVE_SALE | google        | 
| 337        | 2022-05-02  |   99     | 12_WAVE_SALE | google        | 
| 337        | 2022-05-02  |   51     | 12_WAVE_SALE | instagram     |
```

I expect to get this result:

```
| join_id                                            | date        | sessions |
| -------------------------------------------------- | ----------- | -------- |
| 337:utm_campaign=12_WAVE_SALE                      | 2022-05-01  |   100    | 
| 337:utm_campaign=12_WAVE_SALE&utm_source=facebook  | 2022-05-01  |   25     | 
| 337:utm_campaign=12_WAVE_SALE&utm_source=google    | 2022-05-01  |   75     | 
| 337:utm_campaign=12_WAVE_SALE&utm_source=google    | 2022-05-02  |   99     | 
| 337:utm_campaign=12_WAVE_SALE&utm_source=instagram | 2022-05-02  |   51     |
| 337:utm_campaign=12_WAVE_SALE                      | 2022-05-02  |   150    |
```

1. Create join_id with these rules: **counter_id:** + if column is campaign then CONCAT **utm_campaign=...**, if source contains **Not specified** then CONCAT "" (nothing), if it contains another value then CONCAT **&utm_source=...**
2. Group separately and together by campaign and source (with grouping by **counter_id** and **date**). It means that in the result set I expect data with grouping by:

- campaign
- source
- campaign+source

I need this to create all possible combinations.

For example, with another column **medium** if will look like:

- campaign
- campaign + source
- campaign + medium
- campaign + source + medium
- source
- source + medium
- medium

Now I can only create multiple "views" with grouping by these parameters separately and then use union like:

```
select * from .. group by campaign 

union all

select * from ... group by campaign, source

union all...
```

But maybe there is another better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [CUBE](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-cube/) option

If I recreate your case with

```
create table test(counter_id int, date date, sessions int, campaign text, source text);

insert into test values (337, '2022-05-01', 25, '12_WAVE_SALE', 'facebook');
insert into test values (337, '2022-05-01', 100, '12_WAVE_SALE', 'Not specified');
insert into test values (337, '2022-05-01', 75, '12_WAVE_SALE', 'google');
insert into test values (337, '2022-05-01', 99, '12_WAVE_SALE', 'google');
insert into test values (337, '2022-05-01', 51, '12_WAVE_SALE', 'instagram');
```

The following gives more or less what you're looking for

```
select counter_id, date, campaign, source, sum(sessions)
from test
group by 
    cube(counter_id, date, campaign, source)
```